# Installing an ASP.NET web API on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have built my first ASP.NET web API in MVC, when I debug the application from Visual Studio everything works perfectly.

Now I need to get these API's on my server...

I have tried copying the project files to the website root which usually works for normal MVC apps with views, and I have also built the project and copies the file full of DLL's and an exe to the IIS root.

Obviously, neither of these worked, anyone know what I am missing? Perhaps something I have to do with IIS?

I have now tried "publishing" the project and when I try to access the site this happens...[image: Internal server error]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using the web deploy publish method or publish to file system and copy all files.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/

Comment: In what way did they not work?

Comment: I have updated my question to show the results of a publish

Answer (score 1):

Build the application then publish it. Copy the published files to a favorite IIS folder. Ensure you select the right version of ASP.NET in the server for your application in the application pool.

Comment: Have you installed ASP.NET on the server?

Comment: I'm sure it has considering it runs other asp.net websites?

Answer (score 1):

When you publish and get an error such as this it is often related to a configuration issue, or other non-supported .NET Runtime issue.

For best results, if you can get to the Event Viewer for the server a detailed error should appear there outlining the root cause of the issue.

If you don't have access to the server directly, updating the `<system.webServer>` section with the below should get you a detailed error.

> <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />

Just please note DO NOT LEAVE THAT LINE IN PRODUCTION!